# Angular 2 - How to Compare JSON and ngModel object get the difference between them?

Tags: angular

```
  <select multiple [(ngModel)]="budgetSelectedVal "> 
       <option *ngFor="let budgetyear of budgetyears " value = {{budgetyear.value}} > 
                    {{budgetyear.value}} 
       </option>  
  </select>
```

Above code is used for two-way binding the budget years selection's from the dropdown where,

**budgetyears** :

```
[{
        "year": "budgetYear",
        "value": "2018"
    }, {
        "year": "budgetYear",
        "value": "2017"
    }, {
        "year": "budgetYear",
        "value": "2016"
    }, {
        "year": "budgetYear",
        "value": "2015"
    }, {
        "year": "budgetYear",
        "value": "2014"
    }, {
        "year": "budgetYear",
        "value": "2013"
    }, {
        "year": "budgetYear",
        "value": "2012"
    }
]
```

Now I want to compare the budget year's selected values(from the dropdown) against the JSON data return from the server.So for instance for the budget year selected values(2018,2017,2016) I only received the response for the year(2018,2017) and not 2016 then I should be able to display only data for 2018 and 2017 using JSON response and for 2016 I need to set some default values.

JSON response should be something like below:

```
[{
    "budgetYear": "2018",
    "amount": 424.0,
}, {
    "budgetYear": "2017",
    "amount": 1008.0,
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe or do it in typescript using **`.filter`** as shown below,

```
constructor(){ 
       this.budgetyears=this.budgetyears
                        .filter(years=>years.value==this.budgetSelectedVal)
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? I want to loop through the Json response(which contains budgetYears) and compare those year's with the budgetSelectedVal model values and find out the difference between them so that i can use that difference to set the default values and looping the Json response should help me get the actual amount values for whatever years it is available in the response.